# how do manually remove microphone phone permission for camera plugin in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, permissions, camera

Is it possible to remove asking microphone permission for camera plugin for android device using flutter

I have tried like below in my AndroidManifest.xml

but it shows error

Any one can help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" tools:node="remove"/>
i have tried like this

Comment: you can fork the repo and remove it from their and use your forked repo but if you remove that permission wouldn't it break some native implementations and it might happen you won't be able to run your app

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One important thing. enableAudio: false parameter can only be passed as the last parameter to the CameraController. Like below:

```
_controller = CameraController(firstCamera, ResolutionPreset.medium,
    enableAudio: false);
```

All other attempts will cause syntax error. Adding this one helps to avoid adding additional NSMicrophoneUsageDescription in info.plist. Otherwise app will crash with this error:

> "This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive
> data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an
> NSMicrophoneUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the
> user how the app uses this data."

Answer (score 3):

disable audio for camera controller

```
controller = CameraController(
        cameras.first,
        ResolutionPreset.medium,
        enableAudio: false,
        imageFormatGroup: Helpers.isIOS ? ImageFormatGroup.bgra8888 : ImageFormatGroup.yuv420,
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can request camera permission only by passing the parameter **enableAudio: false** to the CameraController (0.5.2+1 ++).